# how can I change UnsafeMutableBufferPointer to withUnsafeMutablePointer?

Tags: swift

I got a warning for the following function after a recent update, I am not sure how to convert it with withUnsafeMutablePointer as indicated by Xcode, not very familiar with swift.

````
        var number: UInt16 = 0
        let realStartIndex = index+self.startIndex
        self.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &number, count: 2), from:
                        realStartIndex..<(realStartIndex+MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size))
        return number
    }```
````

Comment: That code already looks wrong *before* the "recent update". You just want to copy two bytes into `number`, right? Did you actually mean `count: 1`? That is counting the number of `UInt16`s, not the number of bytes. Also, I'm guessing `self` is `Data`?

Comment: Sorry that I missed the first line of the code, as part of the function:
'''    func getUint16At (index:Data.Index) -> UInt16 { '''
The code was inherited from somewhere else, probably the thinking was the count was in bytes as the author probably not good at swift either.  My understanding from your reply was to change to '''count: 1''' as I am just copying one UInt16, but the problem persistent.  It still shows that: Initialization of 'UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt16>' results in a dangling buffer pointer. 
And the problem is how to use withUnsafeMutablePointer to correct it?